# How do I return concrete type when overriding a generically typed method in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, apache-spark, scala-generics

please have a look at the following code snippet:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Time
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds

abstract class MQTTDStream[T <: Any](ssc: StreamingContext) extends DStream(ssc) {
  override def compute(validTime: Time): Option[RDD[T]] =
Some(ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(1, 2, 3), 1)) //This line doesn't compile

  override def dependencies = Nil

  override def slideDuration = Seconds(1) // just an example
}
```

I get the following error:

> type mismatch;  found   : Int(1)  required: T

I've declared T to extend Any, so why is the compiler complaining? Int is a sub-type of Any, isn't it?

Thanks a lot!

Update: 2.9.16:

Changed to extend from DStream[Int] but still the same error:

```
abstract class MQTTDStream[T](ssc: StreamingContext) extends DStream[Int](ssc) {
  override def compute(validTime: Time): Option[RDD[T]] =
Some(ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(1, 2, 3), 1)) //This line doesn't compile

  override def dependencies = Nil

  override def slideDuration = Seconds(1) // just an example
}
```

EDIT: 2.9.16:

Thanks to Alexey, this is the working solution:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Time
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds

abstract class MQTTDStream[T](ssc: StreamingContext) extends DStream[Int](ssc) {
  override def compute(validTime: Time): Option[RDD[Int]] =
    Some(ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(1, 2, 3), 1))

  override def dependencies = Nil

  override def slideDuration = Seconds(1) // just an example
}
```

Comment: whats the point of saying T <: Any? All types are subtypes of Any. Also its not clear which line is throwing an error.

Comment: just added a comment on the line which doesn't compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caller gets to pick `T`, not you. So your class definition must work for all `T` (which satisfies type bounds, but all `T` are subtypes of `Any`).

That is, if someone creates e.g. a `MQTTDStream[String]`, then its `compute` method has to return an `Option[RDD[String]]`. But it doesn't: it returns `Some[RDD[Int]]`.

Comment: Ok, so this means no way to hard code Seq(1, 2, 3) as return type, correct?

Comment: You can, but only if you extend `DStream[Int]` (or `[AnyVal]` or `[Any]`).

Comment: Hi Alexey, I've changed the code (see above) still getting the same error

Comment: You didn't fix the return type of `compute`, it should be `Option[RDD[Int]]`.